# How to simplfy this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query 1:

```
SET @count = 0;
    UPDATE a_daily_copy_copy
    SET a_daily_copy_copy.Cummulative_Target = @count:= target + @count 
    where a_daily_copy_copy.Site_id = 1 
          and a_daily_copy_copy.Year=4 
          and a_daily_copy_copy.Billing_cycle=1
    ORDER BY date
```

Query 2: Modified the a_daily_copy_copy.Billing_cycle=2

```
 SET @count = 0;
    UPDATE a_daily_copy_copy
    SET a_daily_copy_copy.Cummulative_Target = @count:= target + @count
    where a_daily_copy_copy.Site_id = 1 
          and a_daily_copy_copy.Year=4 
          and a_daily_copy_copy.Billing_cycle=2
    ORDER BY date
```

I'm a  beginner and as of now I'm running the query every time manually by editing the query 1 , and I know both queries can be consolidated into a single query.

I tried solving with Group by function but couldnt come up with Please help me.

Have screened the table:
[image]

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result?

Comment: have added the screen shot of the table !!

Comment: are these subsets fixed from business point view (i.e. will there be a need sooner or later to compute the cumulative count in a different way?) if so I would get rid of the cumulative count column and simply query for the count of records in a certain year/billing cycle/site id (add/minus any other restrictions) that have a date less than or equal to a specific date. If cumulative is always going to be grouped by this set of criteria then your query looks good and there's nothing you need to change to improve it.

Comment: suggest a query for what you suggest i.e to query the count of records in a certain period which is greater or lesser to a specific date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you can just do:

```
SET @count = 0;
    UPDATE a_daily_copy_copy
    SET a_daily_copy_copy.Cummulative_Target = @count:= target + @count where a_daily_copy_copy.Site_id = 1 and a_daily_copy_copy.Year=4 and a_daily_copy_copy.Billing_cycle IN (1, 2)
    ORDER BY date
```

...unless I've missed a difference between the two queries other than the billing cycle.

Comment: working for me !! little bit curious to know any other different way to get !!